# How to perform selectinload behind many-to-many?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

With code below:

```
import logging

from faker import Faker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, Session, selectinload

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")

fake = Faker('ru_RU')
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    first_name: Mapped[str]
    last_name: Mapped[str]
    permissions: Mapped[list["Permission"]] = relationship(secondary="user_permission", back_populates="users")


class Level(Base):
    __tablename__ = "level"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    code: Mapped[str]
    permissions: Mapped["Permission"] = relationship(back_populates="level")


class Permission(Base):
    __tablename__ = "permission"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    code: Mapped[str]
    level_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("level.id"))
    level: Mapped["Level"] = relationship(back_populates="permissions")
    users: Mapped[list["User"]] = relationship(secondary="user_permission", back_populates="permissions")


class UserPermission(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_permission"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user.id"))
    permission_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("permission.id"))


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


with Session(engine) as session:
    level = Level(code="red")

    permission1 = Permission(code="create", level=level)
    permission2 = Permission(code="delete", level=level)

    user = User(first_name=fake.first_name(), last_name=fake.last_name())
    user.permissions.extend([permission1, permission2])

    session.add(user)
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    stmt = select(User).options(selectinload(Permission.level))  # this fails with error
    users = session.scalars(stmt).all()
    users[0].permissions[0].level  # this makes sql-request
```

I'd like to perform join `Permission.level`. But code:

```
stmt = select(User).options(selectinload(Permission.level))
```

fails with error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/sa/m2m.py", line
> 71, in 
> users = session.scalars(stmt).all()   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
> line 2337, in scalars
> return self._execute_internal(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
> line 2120, in _execute_internal
> result: Result[Any] = compile_state_cls.orm_execute_statement(   File
> "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py",
> line 293, in orm_execute_statement
> result = conn.execute(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 1412, in execute
> return meth(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py",
> line 483, in _execute_on_connection
> return connection._execute_clauseelement(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 1627, in _execute_clauseelement
> compiled_sql, extracted_params, cache_hit = elem._compile_w_cache(   File
> "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py",
> line 671, in _compile_w_cache
> compiled_sql = self._compiler(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py",
> line 288, in _compiler
> return dialect.statement_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py",
> line 1425, in **init**
> Compiled.**init**(self, dialect, statement, **kwargs)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py",
> line 866, in **init**
> self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)   File
> "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py",
> line 911, in process
> return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py",
> line 143, in _compiler_dispatch
> return meth(self, **kw)  # type: ignore  # noqa: E501   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py",
> line 4576, in visit_select
> compile_state = select_stmt._compile_state_factory(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py",
> line 678, in create_for_statement
> return klass.create_for_statement(statement, compiler, **kw)   File
> "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py",
> line 1116, in create_for_statement
> opt.process_compile_state(self)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategy_options.py", line 905, in process_compile_state
> self._process(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategy_options.py", line 1097, in _process
> loader.process_compile_state(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategy_options.py", line 1649, in process_compile_state
> keys = self._prepare_for_compile_state(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategy_options.py", line 1994, in _prepare_for_compile_state
> self._raise_for_no_match(parent_loader, mapper_entities)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategy_options.py", line 1566, in _raise_for_no_match
> raise sa_exc.ArgumentError( sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapped class Mapper[Permission(permission)] does not apply to any of the root
> entities in this query, e.g. Mapper[User(user)]. Please specify the
> full path from one of the root entities to the target attribute.

What's the `full path`? How to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to chain `selectinload`s for `User.permissions` and `Permission.level`, like this:

```py
stmt = select(User).options(
    selectinload(User.permissions).selectinload(Permission.level)
)
```

(Similar to the second example [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.selectinload)). The "full path" refers to the chain of relationships that you have to follow from the `User` class to the `level` attribute.